# Image upload MVC5

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to upload an image and save it to a file but I can't capture it in the controller as it's always null.

**in the view:**

```cs
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data "}))
{
    ....
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

**Controller:**

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProductID,FKSubCategoryID,ProductEnName,ProductArName,ProductEnDescription,ProductArDescription,ProductImage")] Product product,HttpPostedFileBase file)
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        product.FKBrandID = 1;
        db.Products.Add(product);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

**I have already tried:**

- Using HttpPostedFileBase instead of HttpPostedFile
- `Request.Files["file"]` is **null**
- Name of the parameter in the input and the ActionResult is the same
- `enctype = "multipart/form-data ", data_ajax = "false"`
- Adding `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]`

And this is driving me crazy so please any suggestions?

Comment: How are you submitting this (standard submit or ajax)?

Comment: Using standard submit

Comment: Then what is `data_ajax = "false"`? Which suggests ajax? - If you have `@usng (Html.BeginForm(......, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` it should work fine

Comment: I tried it with and without the data_ajax = "false" just in case..
and I have 
(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data "}))
still no file

Comment: Do you have any other inputs in your view with `name="file"`?

Comment: Not at all, I also tried changing the name of the input...
something is wrong but I can't figure it out

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown to suggest it would not work, so it must be something in the code you have not shown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the value you provided for `enctype`  attribute is not valid !

Take a closer look. You have a space before closing the double quotes!

```
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data "}
```

It should be  `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}`

The below code should work fine.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post,
                                                 new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{  
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
   <input type="submit"/>

}
```